# How to move td content to another td at the same row across borders

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I'm trying to code an animation to push a td content (which is a div inside the td) to another td (to the end of the row) in the same tr across tds borders without changing the width of the td.

Is there a good way to do this? CSS / jQuery?

Comment: There is always a way! But you must try something first and show us your code in order for us to be able to help you!

Comment: this was my first question and I wasn't allowed to upload a picture yet.

Comment: Take the div out of the td, position it on top of the td with the same size and animate it, then on end of the animation, put the div inside the td. Or maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: i have the divs like balls that need to move across the dts in the same line to the other side of the table. a table row looks like this  <tr>
            <td>Isal</td>
            <td>
                <div class="calls" id="agent_1"></div>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
            </td>

            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

Comment: I keep pushing the divs with margin-left but when it reach the end of the td. it takes the td border with it and then the td width keep changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is animation you want (the first td content seems to "slide" into another td with an animation), I came up with this (hopefully I got your question right):

```
$div = $('td.first > div');
$div
    .css({position:'relative'})
    .animate({
        left:$('td.second').offset().left - $('td.first').offset().left
    }, {
        complete:function(){
            $div.appendTo('td.second');
            $div.css({position:'', left:''});
        }, 
        duration:1000
    });
```

So what does it do?

1. Set position of content to "relative". This way, we can move it relative to its original position.
2. animate it so that it goes exactly where it should be if it was inside td.second. We calculate the distance between cells with jquery's offset() function
3. At the end of the animation, we actually copy the div inside the second . Before that it was visually, but not actually in the other td.
4. We remove instantly the position and left css properties. Without this line the the div would be offset from its new position.

I did not test this and it could be optimized.

Comment: i think my qustion wasn't so clear to understand. i doesn't work, thanks anyway

Comment: Can you be more precise? Judging by your comments on the original question, I think this is what you are looking for. margin-left won't work beacuse it extends the parent, that's why I used position:relative here.

Comment: Check this here: http://jsfiddle.net/zjudwumd/ Note that I corrected a typo (position:'relative';} (removed the semi-colon)